# PDO::lastInsertId resets after SELECT in PHP 7.2

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

We're upgrading our application to PHP 7.2 (currently at 7.2.7) from PHP 5.5.9 and stumbled upon the following problem.

When executing an INSERT query and then immediately running lastInsertId, the value it returns is correct. But if a SELECT query is executed in between, lastInsertId returns 0. This did not happen in PHP 5.5.9.

Our MySQL version is 5.7.22, but I don't think that's related since we have the same MySQL version on another machine with PHP 5.5 and we don't have the problem there.

If you run "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();" as a raw query (through PDO) the result you get is correct, so this seems to be a bug with PDO's lastInsertId.

Here is an example code snippet which you can use to reproduce the problem:

```
<?php

$username = "username";
$password = "password";    

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=test_db", $username, $password);
    $pdo->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_table` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `random_field` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;");
    $st = $pdo->query("INSERT INTO test_table(random_field) VALUES (" . rand(1, 100000) . ")");
    if($st){
        echo "last_insert_id: " . $pdo->lastInsertId() . "\n";
        $pdo->query("SELECT 1 + 1");
        echo "last_insert_id: " . $pdo->lastInsertId() . "\n";
    }
    else{
        var_dump($pdo->errorInfo());
    }
```

Comment: Then store it in a local variable, this is normal behaviour.

Comment: It's definitely not "normal" behavior in the sense that:
a) It used to work in PHP 5.5 (just tested again). So was that "abnormal"?
b) As I said, if you ask MySQL directly (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();) it gives you the correct ID. So I would expect the "normal" behavior of PDO should be to give me the same number as MySQL's LAST_INSERT_ID(), not a different one.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your test code on PHP 5.6.37 with MariaDB 5.5.60 and I get this answer:

```
last_insert_id: 4 
last_insert_id: 0
```

So this behaviour is not limited to PHP 7.2. And I don't find the behaviour all that strange, afterall, when you execute a new query on the database a lot of things can happen in the PDO driver.

My suggestion would be, and perhaps this is not what you want to hear, to always ask for the last insert id directly after the insertion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just tested again with PHP 5.5.9 and it works (I get the same ID both times). So maybe it changed with PHP 5.6 (or rather, the php_pdo module that comes with PHP 5.6)? Don't know. In any case, I don't think this is normal behavior, please see my reply to @LawrenceCherone above.

Comment: I have to agree with you that the PHP manual suggest that only a new INSERT will change this ID, but it is not explicitly stated. It does warn you about the variable nature of the result across different PDO drivers. Given that, even if this is a bug, it currently doesn't work as you expect, I see two solutions: 1. Ask for the id immediately after the insert, or 2. ask MySQL directly. That will work in any version of PHP. In my view the first option make most sense, it keeps the insert, and getting the lasted id, together.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, this is not difficult to work around. I was just wondering if it is indeed a bug (that I should report) or if it was an intentional change and somebody knows the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly the php_pdo module that comes with PHP 5.6, because the classic mysql module of PHP 5.6 keeps the last insert id even after a select statement.

We faced this problem with PHP 7.2 because the mysql module is removed in this version and finally many of us choose the pdo_module as an alternative.

To solve this problem i assigned the result in a temporary variable directly after the insert statement.